# TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://XYZ:8080/tfs/ProjectCollection

Tags: tfsbuild

I am getting the error when I do the build though TFS

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \Project\PW_PROD_BUILD: TF30063: You are not authorized to access http://XYZ:8080/tfs/ProjectCollection.

The user ID with which the build happens is tfsserviceuser. The password of this user id is recently changed. I cleared the cache, the network credentials and everything. If I try accessing http://XYZ:8080/tfs/ProjectCollection in Internet explorer with user id tfsserviceuser, I am able to access it.

Please let me know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Do you need to log onto the build server and re-enter the credentials for the Build Service account and restart the build service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear\rename cache folder @

it will change based on version of **TTS** you use:-

```
C:\Users\{User running TFS service}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0
```